# Integrating Facebook and Nextpeer in Android app

Tags: android, facebook, nextpeer

I want to integrate Facebook and Nextpeer in my App. I have facebook login button in my activity and it works fine. I have also nextpeer multiplayer activity which also works fine if I'm not logged in to facebook but when I'm logged in to facebook and try to start multiplayer game than I get error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.AccessTokenSource 
cannot be cast to com.nextpeer.android.facebook.AccessTokenSource
```

So it's seems that nextpeer is trying to login to facebook using class from facebook SDK.

Can anyone help me with that? Please :)

Answer (score 0):

Double check your AndroidManifest.xml file. 
Have you set the right login activity?

It should point to “com.nextpeer.android.facebook.LoginActivity”.

```
  <activity android:name="com.nextpeer.android.facebook.LoginActivity"

                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

                  android:label="@string/np__application_name" />
```

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml is ok. Now i think that it is impossible to connect to facebook via nextpeer and facebook sdk in one app at the same time.

Comment: We fixed the bug. Please download the latest SDK (version 1.3.2) from the Nextpeer website. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote to guy from Nextpeer and he fixed it and now it works fine.